# Accessing free'd memory even without pointing to it

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

So I compiled my program using `gcc -g -static -std=c99 -O2 -o` flags, if you want to look at the code I'll paste it down here, it does simulate a in-memory-filesystem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ENTRIES 1024
#define MAX_NAME 255
#define MAX_PATH 255

#define TYPE_FILE 1
#define TYPE_DIR 2

#define D(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

struct treeNode {
    char* stringa;
    struct treeNode* right;
    struct treeNode* left;
};

struct entry {
    int type;               // type of entry
    void *ptr;              // pointer to the data (next directory entry o file data block)
    char name[MAX_NAME];            // name of the entry (file or directory name)
    struct entry *next;
};

static struct directory {
    int nitems;                 // number of items in the directory 
    struct entry * entries[MAX_ENTRIES];
} root;

/**
 * Prints tree
 *
 * @param pointer to treeRoot
 */
void in_order(struct treeNode *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        in_order(root->left);
        printf("ok %s\n", root->stringa);
        in_order(root->right);
    }
}

/**
 * Destroys tree
 *
 * @param puntatore alla radice dell'albero
 */
void delete_tree(struct treeNode** leaf) {
    if (*leaf != NULL) {
        delete_tree(&(*leaf)->left);
        delete_tree(&(*leaf)->right);
        free((*leaf)->stringa);
        (*leaf)->stringa = NULL;
        free((*leaf));
        *leaf = NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Inserts paths to tree
 *
 * @param ptr to root
 */
void insert_in_tree(char* key, struct treeNode** leaf) {
    int res;
    if (*leaf == NULL) {
        *leaf = (struct treeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode));
        (*leaf)->stringa = malloc(strlen(key)+1);
        strcpy ((*leaf)->stringa, key);
        (*leaf)->left = NULL;
        (*leaf)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        res = strcmp(key, (*leaf)->stringa);
        if( res < 0)
            insert_in_tree( key, &(*leaf)->left);
        else if( res > 0)
            insert_in_tree( key, &(*leaf)->right);
    }
}

/**
 * calculates hash of string
 * 
 * @param s stringa di cui calcolare l'hash code
 * @return codice hash
 */
unsigned int hashcode_string(char *s) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (*s)
        count = count * 31 + *s++;
    return count;
}

/**
 * Creates a child directory/file
 * 
 * @param dir directory in cui cercare 
 * @param name nome da cercare 
 * @return puntatore all' elemento trovato se trovato, NULL se non trovato
 */
struct entry * find_entry(struct directory *dir, char *name) {
    unsigned int hash = hashcode_string(name) % MAX_ENTRIES;

    struct entry *ptr = dir->entries[hash]; 

    while (ptr) {
        if (!strcmp(ptr->name, name)) // found
            return ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next; // next list position
    }

    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Adds elem to path
 * 
 * @param dir directory in cui aggiungere
 * @param type tipo di elemento da aggiungere
 * @param name nome dell'elemento da aggiungere
 * @param ptr puntatore ai dati dell'elemento da aggiungere
 * @return true in caso di successo, false altrimenti
 */
int add_entry(struct directory *dir, int type, char *name, void *ptr) {

    if (dir->nitems == MAX_ENTRIES) {
        if (ptr) {
            free(ptr);
            ptr = NULL;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned int hash = hashcode_string(name) % MAX_ENTRIES;

    struct entry **entry = &(dir->entries[hash]);

    while (*entry) {
        if (!strcmp((*entry)->name, name)) {            // entry con stesso nome già esistente 
            if (ptr) {
                free(ptr);  
                ptr = NULL;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        entry = &((*entry)->next);
    }

    struct entry *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct entry));
    strcpy(tmp->name, name);
    tmp->type = type;
    tmp->ptr = ptr;                     //Allocato ptr ma non sempre usato
    ptr = NULL;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    *entry = tmp;
    tmp = NULL;
    dir->nitems++;
    return 1;

}

/** 
 * Rimuove un entry da una directory
 * 
 * @param dir directory da cui rimuovere
 * @param name nome dell'entry da rimuovere
 * @return true se è stato eliminato un elemento, false se l'elemento non era presente
 */
int remove_entry(struct directory *dir, char *name) {
    unsigned int hash = hashcode_string(name) % MAX_ENTRIES;

    struct entry **ptr = &(dir->entries[hash]);

    while (*ptr && strcmp(name, (*ptr)->name)) {    //Se *ptr esiste e se i nomi coincidono esci dal while
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }

    if (!*ptr) // dato non presente
        return 0;

    // *ptr è il dato da rimuovere
    struct entry *tmp = *ptr;
    *ptr = tmp->next;
    if (tmp->ptr != NULL) {
        free(tmp->ptr);     
    }
    free(tmp);
    dir->nitems--;
    return 1;
}

/**
 * Elabora un path tokenizzandolo in pezzi
 *
 * @param path path da tokeinizzare
 * @return array di puntatori ai vari elementi del path, NULL se path invalido o vuoto
 */
char ** tokenize_path(char *path) {

    static char *result[MAX_PATH];
    int i;

    if (*path != '/') // path non inizia con /
        return NULL;

    result[0] = strtok(path, "/");

    for (i = 1; i < MAX_PATH && result[i-1]; i++) {
        result[i] = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Cerca la directory specificata in una sottodirectory 
 *
 * @param dir directory in cui cercare
 * @param name nome della directory da cercare
 * @return directory se trovata, NULL altrimenti
 */
struct directory * find_directory(struct directory *dir, char *name) {
    struct entry *entry;

    entry = find_entry(dir, name);

    if (entry && entry->type == TYPE_DIR)
        return entry->ptr;
    else
        return NULL;
}

/**
 * Crea una nuova risorsa e la aggiunge al filesystem
 * 
 * @param path path della risorsa da creare
 * @param type tipo di risorsa da creare
 * @return true in caso di successo, false altrimenti
 */
int create_resource(char *path, int type) {
    char **p = tokenize_path(path);
    int i;
    struct directory *dir = &root;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PATH && p[i+1]; i++) { // va a cercare se esistono tutte le directory
        dir = find_directory(dir, p[i]);
        if (!dir)
            return 0;
    }

    if (type == TYPE_FILE)
        return add_entry(dir, TYPE_FILE, p[i], NULL);

    void* ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(struct directory));
    return add_entry(dir, TYPE_DIR, p[i], ptr);
}

/**
 * Ottiene una entry dal suo path
 *
 * @param path path dove cercare
 * @return l'entry in caso di successo, NULL altrimenti
 */
struct entry * get_resource(char *path) {
    char **p = tokenize_path(path);
    int i;
    struct directory *dir = &root;
    if (*path != '/') return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PATH && p[i+1]; i++) { // va a cercare se esistono tutte le directory
        dir = find_directory(dir, p[i]);
        if (!dir)
            return NULL;
    }

    return find_entry(dir, p[i]);
}

/**
 * mostra il contenuto di una directory
 *
 * @param path path della directory
 */
void ls(char *path) {
    struct directory *dir;
    struct entry *entry;

    if (!strcmp(path, "/")) {
        dir = &root;
    } else {
        entry = get_resource(path);

        if (!entry)
            return;

        if (entry->type != TYPE_DIR) {
            puts("Not a directory");
            return;
        }

        dir = entry->ptr;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
        struct entry *e = dir->entries[i];

        while (e) {
            printf("%s %s\n", e->type == TYPE_FILE ? "F" : "D", e->name);
            e = e->next;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Crea un nuovo file 
 * 
 * @param path path del file da creare
 */
void create(char *path) {
    if (create_resource(path, TYPE_FILE))
        puts("ok");
    else 
        puts("no");
}

/**
 * Crea una nuova directory
 *
 * @param path della directory da creare
 */
void create_dir(char *path) {
    if (create_resource(path, TYPE_DIR))
        puts("ok");
    else 
        puts("no");
}

/**
 * Stampa il contenuto del file
 *
 * @param path path del contenuto da stampare
 */
void read(char *path) {
    struct entry *entry = get_resource(path);

    if (!entry || entry->type != TYPE_FILE) {
        puts("no");
        return;
    }

    if (!entry->ptr)
        puts("contenuto ");
    else
        printf("contenuto %s\n", (char*) entry->ptr);
}

/**
 * Scrive il contenuto nel file
 *
 * @param path path del file
 * @param content contenuto da scrivere
 */
void write(char *content, char *path) {
    //D("%s %s", path, content);

    if (content == NULL) {
        puts("no");
        return;
    }

    struct entry *entry = get_resource(path);
    char *c = strrchr(content, '\"'); // search last "

    if (*content != '\"' || !c || c == content ||!entry || entry->type != TYPE_FILE) {
        puts("no");
        return;
    }

    *c = '\0';
    content++;

    if (entry->ptr)
        free(entry->ptr);

    entry->ptr = (char*) malloc(strlen(content)+1);
    strcpy(entry->ptr, content);
    printf("ok %lu\n", strlen(content));
}

/**
 * Elimina un file dal filesystem
 *
 * @param path path del file da eliminare
 */
void delete(char *path) {
    char **p = tokenize_path(path);
    int i;
    struct directory *dir = &root;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PATH && p[i+1]; i++) { // va a cercare se esistono tutte le directory
        dir = find_directory(dir, p[i]);
        if (!dir)
            goto error;
    }

    struct entry *entry = find_entry(dir, p[i]);

    if (!entry)
        goto error; // file o directory non esistente

    if (entry->type == TYPE_DIR) {
        struct directory *d = entry->ptr;
        if (d->nitems != 0) 
            goto error; // directory non vuota
    }

    if (remove_entry(dir, p[i])) {
        puts("ok");
        return;
    }

error:
    puts("no");
}

/**
 * Elimina ricorsivamente entry da directory
 *
 * d directory da cui eliminare l'entry
 * entry entry da eliminare da d
 */
int delete_rec(struct directory *d, struct entry *entry) {
    int status = 0;
    struct directory *dir;

    if (entry == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (entry->type == TYPE_FILE)
        return remove_entry(d, entry->name);

    dir = entry->ptr;

    if (dir->nitems != 0) {
        // itera su tutti gli elementi della directory
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
            struct entry *e = dir->entries[i];  //Scorre tutti gli elem di /foo (bar e baz)

            while (e) {
                status += delete_rec(dir, e);
                e = e->next;            
            }                   
        }
    }
    status += remove_entry(d, entry->name);

    return status;
}

/**
 * Elimina un file dal filesystem ricorsivametne, 
 * eliminando anche i figli nel caso di directory
 *
 * @param path path del file da eliminare
 */
void delete_r(char *path) {
    char **p = tokenize_path(path);
    int i;
    struct directory *dir = &root;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PATH && p[i+1]; i++) { // va a cercare se esistono tutte le directory
        dir = find_directory(dir, p[i]);
        if (!dir)
            goto error;
    }

    struct entry *entry = find_entry(dir, p[i]);

    if (!entry)
        goto error;

    if (delete_rec(dir, entry))
        puts("ok");
    else
error:
        puts("no");
}

/**
 * Costruisce una stringa della path 
 * 
 * @param path array dei path
 * @param level numero di parti della path
 * @param name nome del file finale
 * @return stringa nuova allocata
 */
void build_path(char *path[], int level, char *name, struct treeNode** rootOfTree) {
    char tmp[MAX_PATH*MAX_NAME];

    strcpy(tmp, "/");
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        strcat(tmp, path[i]);
        strcat(tmp, "/");
    }
    strcat(tmp, name);
    insert_in_tree(tmp, rootOfTree);
}

/**
 * Cerca ricorsivamente 
 *
 * @param dir directory in cui cercare
 * @param path array dei path 
 * @param level livello di ricorsione 
 * @param name nome da cercare 
 * @param founds array dei path cercati
 * @param index numero di file trovati
 */
void find_rec(struct directory *dir, char *path[], int level, char *name, int *index, struct treeNode** rootOfTree) {
    // itera su tutti gli elementi della directory
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
        struct entry *e = dir->entries[i];

        while (e) {
            if (!strcmp(e->name, name)) {
                (*index)++;
                build_path(path, level, name, rootOfTree);
            } // trovato elemento

            if (e->type == TYPE_DIR) {
                path[level] = e->name;
                find_rec(e->ptr, path, level+1, name, index, rootOfTree);
            }
            e = e->next;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Cerca il nome nel filesystem
 *
 * @param name nome da cercare
 */
void find(char *name) {
    struct treeNode* rootOfTree = NULL;
    char *path[MAX_PATH];

    int nfound = 0;

    find_rec(&root, path, 0, name, &nfound, &rootOfTree);

    if (nfound == 0) {
        puts("no");
        return;
    }

    if (rootOfTree != NULL) {
        in_order(rootOfTree);
        delete_tree(&rootOfTree);
    } else puts("Albero null ma stampa");
}

#define CMD(name, ...)          \
if (!strcmp(cmd, #name)) {  \
    name(__VA_ARGS__);      \
    continue;               \
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[MAX_NAME*MAX_NAME+255];
    FILE* fp = fopen("/Users/mattiarighetti/Desktop/semplice.in", "r");
    while (1) {
        //printf("cmd> ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    if (*line != '\n') {
        char *message = strchr(line, '"');
            char *cmd = strtok(strtok(line, "\n"), " ");
        char *ARG = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (cmd != NULL && ARG != NULL && *ARG=='/' && message == NULL) { 
            CMD(create, ARG)
                CMD(create_dir, ARG)
                CMD(read, ARG)
                CMD(delete, ARG)
                CMD(delete_r, ARG)
                CMD(ls, ARG);
                puts("no");
        } else if ((!strcmp(cmd, "find")) && ARG != NULL) {
            CMD(find, ARG)
        }else if (cmd != NULL && (!strcmp(cmd, "write")) && message != NULL && ARG != NULL && *message == '"' && *ARG == '/') {
            CMD(write, message, ARG)    
        } else if (cmd != NULL && !strcmp(cmd, "exit")) {
            CMD(exit, 0)
        } else { 
            puts("no"); 
            continue; 
        }
    } else { puts("no"); continue; }
    }

}
```

and it returns me a segmentation fault. I've been investigating on what the problem could have been and valgrind tells me that I am accessing free'd memory.

```
==816== Invalid read of size 8
==816==    at 0x100001567: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:454)
==816==    by 0x10000169A: delete_r (FILESYS.c:485)
==816==    by 0x100001BF8: main (FILESYS.c:587)
==816==  Address 0x100b65c60 is 272 bytes inside a block of size 280 free'd
==816==    at 0x10009B96B: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-16470/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==816==    by 0x100000C72: remove_entry (FILESYS.c:189)
==816==    by 0x1000014FE: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:442)
==816==    by 0x10000155C: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:452)
==816==    by 0x10000169A: delete_r (FILESYS.c:485)
==816==    by 0x100001BF8: main (FILESYS.c:587)
==816==  Block was alloc'd at
==816==    at 0x10009BBF2: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-16470/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==816==    by 0x100000AF6: add_entry (FILESYS.c:151)
==816==    by 0x100000E96: create_resource (FILESYS.c:254)
==816==    by 0x100001109: create (FILESYS.c:322)
==816==    by 0x100001B44: main (FILESYS.c:583)
==816== 
==816== Invalid read of size 8
==816==    at 0x100001567: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:454)
==816==    by 0x10000155C: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:452)
==816==    by 0x10000169A: delete_r (FILESYS.c:485)
==816==    by 0x100001BF8: main (FILESYS.c:587)
==816==  Address 0x100b61330 is 272 bytes inside a block of size 280 free'd
==816==    at 0x10009B96B: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-16470/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==816==    by 0x100000C72: remove_entry (FILESYS.c:189)
==816==    by 0x1000014FE: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:442)
==816==    by 0x10000155C: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:452)
==816==    by 0x10000155C: delete_rec (FILESYS.c:452)
==816==    by 0x10000169A: delete_r (FILESYS.c:485)
==816==    by 0x100001BF8: main (FILESYS.c:587)
==816==  Block was alloc'd at
==816==    at 0x10009BBF2: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-16470/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==816==    by 0x100000AF6: add_entry (FILESYS.c:151)
==816==    by 0x100000E96: create_resource (FILESYS.c:254)
==816==    by 0x100001109: create (FILESYS.c:322)
==816==    by 0x100001B44: main (FILESYS.c:583)
```

Indeed the problem does occur in the `delete_rec` function, as soon as the recursive `delete_rec` comes back from its first run. I don't know why but that `e->next` does point to something, since I've always made it point to NULL (when I do not have collision in the hashmap) and if it doesn't at least it should point to the next item in the linked list used to fix collisions. Instead with `gdb` I've discovered that it does point to an area `0x120` and it shoudn't.

```
while (e) {
    status += delete_rec(dir, e);
    e = e->next;            
}
```

Of course when `e` becomes something different than `NULL` the `delete_rec` does not stop the function and it returns a segfault.

According to valgrind that pointer points to an area that has just been freed, but `e->next` did not point the memory that I've free's. The one I free'd was pointed, in this case, by `e->ptr`, how can that be possible?

Comment: Accessing memory you don't own (like memory recently released by `free`)  leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And UB makes your program (the *whole* program) *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: As for how it's possible to access it, well the memory is still physically there. And the `free` function doesn't modify the pointer (it can't, since it's passed by value as all arguments in C).

Comment: The problem here is that I don't think that I've accessed to it since the memory pointed by `e->next` shouldn't be pointing to the memory I just free'd @Someprogrammerdude As I wrote, I free'd memory pointed by `e->ptr`

Comment: By the way, for future questions please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do *you* modify `e->next` (or `e->ptr`) anywhere after passing it to `free`? Do *you* make it a null pointer? No? Then it won't magically change its value.

Comment: Yes but I didn't free that memory yet, that is the awkward thing. I might be mistaken somewhere perhaps but it's the third time I debug this code and that pointer has never been changed since I did not have any collision and therefore I didn't have to attach a `struct entry` to that `e->next` pointer.
Well I do modify `e->ptr` but why does it make difference for the other `e->next` value? They're pointing to different things, and actually the problem here is just with `e->next` not the other one, which is free'd correctly and since I've made `e->ptr` a NULL it can't get back to that memory.

Comment: This is really not a free debugging service, you should learn how to use a debugger and step through code yourself to help you figure out problems like this. *However* as I'm feeling kind I will give you a hint: While looping over the entries and recursively calling `delete_rec`, you might free the entry pointed to by `e`, but you don't actually update the variable `e` itself. It will still point to the free'd structure. Then when you dereference it with `e->next` you will have *undefined behavior*. This would be clear if you used a debugger and checked the pointers (or even printed them).

Comment: I recommend to you, follow MISRA coding standard after that debug the issue. you will find where is the misbehavior in code.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to produce a huge number of warning messages.  Strongly suggest fixing those warnings, especially as some of them are outright errors in the code.  When compiling always enable the warnings.   (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11`  and just to help for you to fix the problems, suggest `-Werror`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent). 4) strings of calls to goto() make the code much more difficult to read/understand and are error prone.  5) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: When calling most system functions: (for instance, `fopen()`, `fgets()`), always check the returned code to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: It is a poor programming practice to have multiple items in the code with the same spelling, but differences in capitalization.  For instance `CMD` and `cmd` as that leads to confusion and problems when debugging.

Comment: when calling the function: `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value before using that value.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `char *cmd = strtok(strtok(line, "\n"), " ");
            char *ARG = strtok(NULL, " ");`  due to the prior call to `fgets(), there will be nothing after the '\n' byte in 'line[]' other than a NUL byte. so the second call to `strtok()` will either, always return NULL or it will access some random value beyond the actual data in 'line[]' including data beyond the end of the array 'line[]'  In either case, this is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 yes I know that and that is intentional. I need to store a command that is given with the entry key, so that works like a charm in my case.